# ASP.NET Core custom binding ModelName always empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have implemented custom binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var modelAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelAsString))
        {
            // custom login here
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and corresponding model binder provider:

```
public class CustomModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(CustomModel))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and I have added custom binder provider to ModelBinderProviders collection:

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomModelBinderProvider()));
```

Everything works except one thing. Custom binder is being called but unfortunatelly bindingContext.ModelName is always empty and don't know why. As ModelName is empty I always get ValueProviderResult.None as value provider.

```
var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName; //ModelName is empty here
var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName); // I will get ValueProviderResult.None on this line
```

I don't know what am I missing in terms of ModelName and ValueProvider.

**UPDATE:**
CustomModel is used in controller which inherites ApiController. Method signature in controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpsertModel(string Id, [FromBody] CustomModel model)
```

Comment: One more question: What data are you providing in the request to bind with?

Comment: It is just very simple JSON: { "Id": "test" }. It is valid for CustomModel type (can be deserialized). Actually it successfuly binds to object without custom binder but I need to do some custom logic in custom binder.

Comment: If you're looking at deserialising a JSON body, you might be better off looking at customising JSON.NET with a custom converter, etc, rather than trying to use a custom model-binder. Model-binders aren't really used with JSON bodies, except just to pass control over to JSON.NET.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thank you for advise. I understand that there are different approches how to achieve this. I am converting old ASP.NET web api app to Core and this is appoach which has been used so I would like to keep it. Even if I use different approach I would like to understand why this custom binder doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, understood. Things do work a little differently in ASP.NET Core, so I'm not sure that you can get access to a JSON body from `ValueProvider`. If you don't get an answer within the next day or two, I'll run up an example and see what I can find out for you.

Comment: I looked into this and found out that you just can't get values from a JSON body using `ValueProvider`. You might have to consume the body yourself.